# Configuration dnsdist

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns, lua

Trying to install PowerDNS 4.1 
Authoritative at 127.0.0.1:5300 
Recursor at 127.0.0.1:5301

Dnsdist config [as in documentation](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/guides/recursion.html#install-and-configure-dnsdist) 
But get an error:

```
# dnsdist -C dnsdist.conf 
Fatal Lua error: Unknown Lua error
```

input:1: attempt to call a nil value (global 'setLocal')

**dnsdist.conf**

```
setLocal('PUBLIC_IPv4')
addLocal('PUBLIC_IPv6')
setACL('PUBLIC_IPv4/24')

newServer({'127.0.0.1:5300', pool='auth'})
newServer({'127.0.0.1:5301', pool='recursor'})

recursive_ips = newNMG()
recursive_ips:addMask('127.0.0.1/8')
recursive_ips:addMask('PUBLIC_IPv4/24')

addAction(NetmaskGroupRule(recursive_ips), PoolAction('recursor'))
addAction(AllRule(), PoolAction('auth'))
```

What`s wrong?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that `setLocal` wouldn't exist. No funny business like invisible characters in front or after it? (`hexdump -C dnsdist.conf`?)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/RomanBogachev/d2ee693fdd3c28f48ca6d26c4466f780

Comment: setLocal is new in v1.2.0 maybe you're running an older version and just use addLocal instead.

Comment: Name        : dnsdist
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.2.0